# A Cryptogram for weeding out the riff raff

Tags: cipher

The cipher is astounding.

> Prja, Y ekd psjlymd fuev yfr lywrqy
>    Gily fsxovh k yfovl
>    Pjqm k dvshr ug k htu
>    Dsxr br km qbya povl.
>    Prja yy ljuph zq ii
>    Oe yuph zq nr dttitydq
>    Jq jkf k qyvh-ii ywizl
>    Kma yfr arxoj'd quqd
>    Fr lyktqf ky br
>    Kma O srjy k vfsvhq
>    Yyzq zqsvy vpejymd
>    Mqbqt pptaa sdsym.

Hurry up and solve it, as time is fleeting.

Hint: as with my previous puzzle, there's a tag left off because it would give too much away.

(The task is to describe the cipher I am using - I don't know if it has a formal name, a description of the process is sufficient)

Comment: Giving no hint doesn't encourange people to work on this...

Comment: @leoll2 - There are three hints other than the explicit one.

Comment: There are definitely hints... If you can't see them, maybe take a jump to the left or a step to the right.

Comment: @IanMacDonald let's do the time warp again?

Comment: Something to do with [this](http://www.stlyrics.com/lyrics/therockyhorrorpictureshow/thetimewarp.htm)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I spent too long thinking about this before I realized, with a groan, that the cipher is

> Just a jump to the left, and then a step to the right.

More specifically:

> The first letter is two keys left on a QWERTY keyboard, wrapping around (so W->Q->P).
>  The next letter is one key right (e->r).
>  Repeat for the rest of the letters (l->k->j, l->a, etc.).

So the plaintext is:

> Well, I was walking down the street
>  Just having a think
>  When a snake of a guy
>  Gave me an evil wink.
>  Well he shook me up
>  He took me by surprise
>  He had a pick-up truck
>  And the devil's eyes
>  He stared at me
>  And I felt a change
>  Time meant nothing
>  Never would again.
>
>  (The last verse of Time Warp from Rocky Horror Picture Show)

Comment: Well done. I hope the madness of the puzzle didn't take its toll too much. :P